# Magento Redis "Read error or connection" in every 5 minutes when cron run

Tags: php, redis, magento-1.14, cm-redissession

We are running magento EE ver. 1.14.1.0. It was running fine for a long, but suddenly we got an issue as follows in storefront.

Redis Read error on connection

> Uncaught exception 'CredisException' with message 'read error on
>   connection' in
>   /var/www/vhosts/project/httpdocs/lib/Credis/Client.php:631
>
> Sample stack trace
>
> …:__call called at /var/www/vhosts/project/httpdocs/lib/Credis/
>   Client.php (440)
>
> …alled at /var/www/vhosts/project/httpdocs/lib/Cm/Cache/Backend/
>   Redis.php (117)
>
> …_construct called at /var/www/vhosts/project/httpdocs/lib/Zend/
>   Cache.php (153)
>
> …akeBackend called at /var/www/vhosts/project/httpdocs/lib/Zend/
>   Cache.php (94)
>
> …/var/www/vhosts/project/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/
>   Cache.php (137)
>
> …var/www/vhosts/project/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/
>   Config.php (1354)
>
> …getModelInstance called at /var/www/vhosts/project/httpdocs/app/
>   Mage.php (463)
>
> …t /var/www/vhosts/project/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/
>   App.php (401)
>
> …t /var/www/vhosts/project/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/
>   App.php (269)
>
> …_Model_App::init called at /var/www/vhosts/project/httpdocs/app/
>   Mage.php (616)
>
> in Mage::app called at /var/www/vhosts/project/httpdocs/index.php (89)

This happens every 5 minutes when magento default cronjob runs.

We tried increasing `read_timout`, disabling `redis` snapshot feature etc. But no luck.

Our redis version is 3.2.10